# How to centre a div within a bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a column, and inside that column, a set of 4 headings wrapped in a div. I would like this div to be centred, however can only get it so the start of the text is at the midpoint - I would like to subtract half of the width of this div, whilst keeping all of the headings starting at the same place:

```
<header>
    <div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div  style="margin-left: 50%;">
                    <h3>> 1</h3>                
                    <h3>> 2</h3>
                    <h3>> 3</h3>
                    <h3>> 4</h3>                
                    <h3>> 5</h3>
                    <h3>> 6</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</header>
```

The row itself, and the column, is centred (horizontally aligned) in the page - but I want the contents of that column to be centred.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: `<div  class="mx-auto" >` should be enough with bs4 or do `<div class="col-md-5 d-flex flex-column align-center"><!-- nodiv --> <hx>1</hx>...</div>`

Comment: Would you like the div horizontally and vertically aligned?

Comment: Horizontally aligned

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Neither of those suggestions work unfortunately.

Comment: Use text-center on the column and remove the margin-left

Answer (score 1):

here is a possible example...

```css
/* show me horizontal center */
body {background:linear-gradient(to left, pink 50%, hotpink 50%)}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-5 d-flex ">
                <div  class="mx-auto">
                    <h3>> 1</h3>                
                    <h3>> 2</h3>
                    <h3>> 3</h3>
                    <h3>> 4</h3>                
                    <h3>> 5</h3>
                    <h3>> 6</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</header>
```